# Using more than one keypair (ssh)

Tags: linux, ssh

I've created a server on Digital Ocean and made a keypair for connection over ssh for the root user. Now it wants me to create a keypair for the new regular user I've created. What is the normal practice for naming these keys and how do I use them so the system knows which keys to use when I'm signing in to each account?

Answer (score 0):

Name them however you wish to remember them; typically by user.  Use the identify file option when you connect.

To connect with a file:

`ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@host`

To generate a new file and save it somewhere

`ssh-keygen -f /path/to/file`

See `man ssh && man ssh-keygen`

See: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1

See: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Comment: I've seen reference to this key.pem file elsewhere but don't have one in my .ssh/ folder. my keys are by default named id_rsa and id_rsa.pub where does .pem fit in?

Comment: You need to download it and save it somewhere from your provider, or generate a new one (see edit).  A pem file is essentially a certificate validating that you are you ... see https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file